# How to add submit button and show the hidden <div> when you click on it in hook_form_alter method

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, hook, alter

I'm hiding a `<div>` using css and i want it to display when i click on the button.

here is my code,

```
function jobs_form_search_api_saved_searches_save_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['set'] = array(

        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('set'),
        '#submit' => array('jobs_search_alert_mail_submit'),
        '#weight' => 3,
         );

             }
```

I'm able to add set button, can anyone help me how do i show hidden `<div>` when i click on the button?

Comment: Is that drupal or something? If so, you should add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your question has no additional HTML or JS, here is a **basic** example how you could achieve this.

**CSS**

```
#hiddenDiv{
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
<button id="showDiv">Show it!</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#showDiv').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenDiv').show(1000);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqLdd24j/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

First, you are defining a `_form_alter` hook, so make sure that you are altering only the form you want, by either checking `$form_id`'s value, or by naming your function `HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter`.

Submitting a form usually sends a synchronous HTTP request that will produce a reload. If the goal is to override that and instead have an AJAX behaviour, you should have a look at the [Form API's `#ajax` property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax).

If your goal is just to hook on the button click event, to display a box between the moment user clicked the button, and the page reloaded (and not prevent the normal submission process), then you only need to insert a new Javascript file, and do something like

```
$('form#FORM_ID').submit(function() {
  $('.YOUR_HIDDEN_DIV').show();
}
```